# I'm trying to create a regex validation for a street address that has the first letter of each word capitalized

Tags: regex, google-forms

I have looked at a few examples and this almost works, but it won't allow numbers

```
\b[a-z]*
```

I am using google forms and want to validate that when someone puts in an address that all the first letters are capitalized in the word.  If I use this to make sure that all lower case words are not in there it kind of works....but not really as any word that has a cap in the middle would also work.

So I want this to be validated

```
124 Main Street 
not
124 main Street
or
124 Main street
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general regex pattern which should work:

```regex
^\d+(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)+$
```

### Demo

This regex says to match:

```regex
^           from the start of the address
\d+         a street number
(?:
    [ ]     space, followed by
    [A-Z]   a capital first letter
    [a-z]*  zero or more following lowercase letters
)+
$           the end of the address
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works for street addresses, but then I realized that I have to allow it to also validate P.O. Boxes which don't start with a number.

Comment: ...then you should ask a new question.  You have 2 answers here to the question you did actually ask above.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you again for the help.  Your answer was perfect, but obviously, I failed to have the correct question.  Thanks for the advice to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*\s[a-z][a-z]).+
```

Explanation:

`^` - anchor - match beginning of a string

`(?!.*\s[a-z]{2})` - egative lookahead - assert what follows does not contain `\s` whitespace followed by two lowercase letters (so does not have word starting with lowercase letter)

`.+` - match one or more of any character.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3IG2r1/1)

Comment: This was a great idea as well, as it wouldn't care if there was a number to start with, but google forms does not like it.  Maybe they are using a different regex version?  I think that it does not like the look aroud.  I was able to take your idea and use

Comment: Let me try that again.

Comment: This was a great idea as well, as it wouldn't care if there was a number to start with, but google forms does not like it.  Maybe they are using a different regex version?  I think that it does not like the look around maybe.  You can choose between contains, matches, does not contain and does not match the regex pattern